# Is it necessary to add Spring Web when using Spring Actuator?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I'm trying to in corporate Spring Actuator to my application. I have added the dependency in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

But I get a 404 when trying to access the `/health` endpoint. After looking online, I've read that I need to also have the `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency in my POM. I was under the assumption that I **only** need the actuator dependency in order to get it working

Comment: If you want them to be accessible from the web you will obviously need the web part as well.

Comment: You can test what dependencies are needed by creating the project using https://start.spring.io/ - it would confirm your suspiciion that you need the web-starter

Answer (score 1):

Yes web is needed if you want to access via HTTP (otherwise only JMX is available).

The [documentation for actuator](https://spring.io/guides/gs/actuator-service/) states

"Click Dependencies and select **Spring Web** and Spring Boot Actuator."